# How to animate Progressbar.js when comes visible in the browser with Waypoints?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I'm using [Progressbar.js](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/) to create an animated progress bar. But the thing is when I place it down, it before it comes into view.
I'm using [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) to trigger the animation only when visible, but I'm not getting it right.

Please help me figure it out.

Thank You.

```js
var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container, {
        strokeWidth: 5,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
        duration: 1400,
        color: '#FFEA82',
        trailColor: '#eee',
        trailWidth: 2,
    });

    bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

```css
#container{
  margin-top:500px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/progressbar.js/1.0.1/progressbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>


scroll down
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple waypoints will do. but note that, by default waypoints will trigger only when element reach the top of the page. scrolling page just to make it appear at the bottom is not enough. it's has to be all the way up or you can use `offset` parameter to help.

```js
var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container, {
        strokeWidth: 5,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
        duration: 1400,
        color: '#FFEA82',
        trailColor: '#eee',
        trailWidth: 2,
    });

    $("#container").waypoint(function(){
       bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
    }, {offset: "50%"})
```

```css
#container{
  margin-top:500px;
  margin-bottom:500px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/progressbar.js/1.0.1/progressbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>


scroll down
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Its not working though. Please check my [codepen](https://codepen.io/kannan3024/pen/yVbpWr)
and if there's any other way we can do it please let me know.

Comment: From your codepen, 
 first, In the external scripts tab, jQuery must be before waypoints script.
 and second, waypoints-2.0.3 is outdated and not compatible with jquery-3, try this instead: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js

Comment: one more thing at last. Its not working for multiple progress bars. Please see the same codepen. Please help.

Comment: Anyone for help? The above code is just working for one progressbar, if I add multiple its just triggers the last one in the stack.

Comment: I don't see how you add multiple progressbar in codepen. please leave your codepen where it's not working, so people can check.

Comment: [codepen] (https://codepen.io/kannan3024/pen/yVbpWr)
I've added 2 more div's and I've duplicated the jQuery and replaced the container names

Comment: well, you re-using `var bar`.  you suppose to use different var for each. may be `var bar2` and `var bar3`.

Comment: Congrats :), please dont forget to accept the answer.